# John the Ripper is unable to crack my SHA1 hashed password

Tags: hash, password-cracking, sha, john-the-ripper

John the Ripper is unable to crack my SHA1 hashed password:

```
john --wordlist=rockyou.txt testing.txt
```

Whenever I do this in Kali Linux, I get this response:

```
Loaded 1 password hash (Raw-SHA1 [SHA1 256/256 AVX2 8x]) Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=2
```

Then, when I try to show the password with:

```
john --show testing.txt
```

I get this:

```
0 password hashes cracked, 1 left
```

The content of `testing.txt` is:

```
7b96bcf29b0982c3fd78f129a432e640346515b1
```

I've tried using every option there is under `--format=` but still no luck.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax based on the information provided should be:

```
galoget@hackem:~$ john -format:RAW-SHA1 -wordlist:rockyou.txt testing.txt
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (Raw-SHA1 [SHA1 256/256 AVX2 8x])
Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=8
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
Warning: Only 1 candidate left, minimum 8 needed for performance.
kaiaisthecutest  (?)
1g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2021-07-11 18:31) 0.9900g/s 14201Kp/s 14201Kc/s 14201KC/s 
Use the "--show --format=Raw-SHA1" options to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
Session completed
```

Where `testing.txt` contains one line with the hash:

```
7b96bcf29b0982c3fd78f129a432e640346515b1
```

If you want to show it after cracking it, you can use the following command:

```
galoget@hackem:~$ john --show testing.txt
?:kaiaisthecutest

1 password hash cracked, 0 left
```

As you can see, the command works, I think that the reason of why you could not crack the hash is that you don't have a dictionary with the correct word.

Comment: Sorry, quick question. So the reason it didn't work is that the password wasn't in rockyou.txt?

Comment: Yes, that exact word is not present in the common `rockyou.txt` file that comes with Kali Linux by default.